# Are measurements of a experiment scalars of Random Variables?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, variance, random-variable, descriptive-statistics, covariance

Random variable can be written as:

```
R = A + B
```

where

- R - random variable
- A - true value
- B - error (also Random Variable)

Suppose now that `B`  as a Random Variable has a mean of 0. So then random variable `R`  has mean as `A`  (true value) and standard deviation as standard deviation of `B` .

So now, we have our random variable `R` defined. Now I am coming to my confusing part. Suppose we are calculating distance between two points A-B. So we are obtaining measurements `x_i`. These measurements are nothing but samples generated by a random variable that depicts this experiment of measuring distances.

So to sum up, experiment is random variable, and measurements are samples (scalars) of this experiment.

I am confused now, because some people say that `x_i` are actually random variables also. This example gives me confusion, since because of it, it makes sense to look at each measurement as random variable.

[image: Example]

To continue, questions says: **Propagate the variance** of the measurements to the sum. So propagation of variance would be `F * variance * F'`. So for sum, F would be vector filled with values 1. This example shows that each measurement is actually random variable which has its own standard deviation (even though it is the same for all) and according to that we should fill our variance matrix with those values.

Can someone explain me this in bit more detail, it would be very helpful, this confuses me. From my perspective both makes sense (that measurements are only samples/scalars and that they are random variables for itself), but I am not quite sure what is right.

Comment: There is some conflict in notation: first $B$ is random then $B$ becomes a value...

Comment: No. B is random variable (error) that has mean=0 and some standard deviation.

Comment: Ok, hard to spot, but I see now; you say `B` is r.v. and B is a value.

Comment: Sorry in the picture A and B are points. I just noticed that. But `A` and `B` in my text are as I mentioned.